# Missing elements from parsed xml result

Tags: php, xml

I have a rss feed which has items in following format

```
<item>
  <title>How Are World's Top Investors Positioning?</title>   
  <guid>123456789</guid>
  <metadata:id>3000121785</metadata:id> 
  <metadata:thumbnail>http://thumbnails.com/abc/xyz.jpg</metadata:thumbnail> 
  <metadata:smallThumbnail>http://thumbnails.com/abc/xyz_s.jpg</metadata:smallThumbnail> 
  <metadata:largeThumbnail>http://thumbnails.com/abc/xyz_l.jpg</metadata:largeThumbnail>   
  <metadata:formatLink>mpeg4_500000_Download|http://thumbnail.com/sample_L.mp4</metadata:formatLink> 
  <metadata:formatLink>mpeg4_200000_Download|http://thumbnail.com/sample__126K.mp4</metadata:formatLink> 
  <metadata:formatLink>mpeg4_600000_Download|http://thumbnail.com/sample__500K.mp4</metadata:formatLink>   
  </item>
```

Upon paring using simple xml

```
$data =  simplexml_load_string($response);
print_r($data);
```

The output of print_r looks like

```
[item] => Array
    ( 
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [title] => How Are World's Top Investors Positioning?    
            [guid] => 123456789
        )
    )
```

My question is why am i missing the metadata portion from the final result and how can i get it in an array?

Comment: This script should not run .. it should return `Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: namespace error : Namespace prefix metadata on id is not defined in`

Comment: @Baba - the XML quoted is not a full RSS feed; he's clearly snipped out a single item from the feed to demonstrate his question. Given that his code clearly does work (up to the point of the question), I would assume that the full feed would include the namespace declaration.

Comment: @prashant i think you should ass your full XML with the headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `metadata` namespace.

```
$metadata = $obj->children('metadata', true);
print $metadata->thumbnail;
```

The following may help you:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getdocnamespaces.php
- http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Comment: @Baba - no, it was from memory, not having a PHP easily to hand. Hopefully even if it's not quite right, it'll at least point the OP in the right dirction.

Comment: @Baba - do you mean my code would return a warning? I guess it would depend on what `$obj` is set to, but it's fairly simple code and seems right to me (I just double-checked from the manual page). Assuming the OP's code currently works as described, what warning would you expect my code to get?

Comment: @SDC : Thanks for the links. The issue was related to namespace & third link helped me understand and fix the problem